# Converter data, como proceder?

Tags: java

Estou com um pequeno problema em meu código.

No meu banco quando salvo a data 03/07/2017 ele funciona, mas no banco da empresa da minha família, só funciona se eu entrar com a data 07/03/2017.

Essa data o funcionário entra de acordo com os teste realizado no mês, então.. ele irá digitar essa data e logo depois irá para uma outra tela onde eu trago essa data para um `jtextfield`.

Gostaria de saber como faço para quando trazer essa data, ele venha no formato 07/03/2017, pois só é salvo quando vai para essa outra tela.

Segue os códigos.

```
// primeira tela
    CadResultado tela = new CadResultado(EntradadadosPerfil.getSelectedItem().toString(), EntradadadosData.getText(), EntradadadosHora.getText(), EntradadadosRegistro.getText());
                tela.setVisible(true);
                dispose();


//segunda tela
    String perfil = "";
    String data = "";
    String hora = "";
    String registro = "";

//segunda tela
perfil = _perfil;
data = _data;
hora = _hora;
registro = _registro;
txt_perfil.setText((perfil));
txt_data.setText((data));
txt_hora.setText((hora));
txt_registro.setText((registro));
```

código para salvar

```
int p = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Você deseja realmente salvar?", "Salvar", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
if (p == 0) {
    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
        for (int i = 0; i < CadresultadoTabela.getRowCount(); i++) {
            String resultado_numerico = new String();
            String resultado_texto = new String();
            String observacao = new String();
            String aprovado = new String();

            try {
                resultado_numerico = CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 30).toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                resultado_numerico = "";
            }

            try {
                resultado_texto = CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 31).toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                resultado_texto = "";
            }

            try {
                observacao = CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 32).toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                observacao = "";
            }

            try {
                aprovado = CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 33).toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                aprovado = "";
            }

            if ((resultado_numerico != "" || resultado_texto != "") && aprovado != "") {
                String sql = "INSERT INTO Resultado (ORDEM,LINHA,LINHA_TIPO,LINHA_SETOR,RCPERFIL,BPCS,"
                                + "DPERFIL,PROJETO,OEM,N_DESENHO,N_PLANO,OPERACAO,EQUIPAMENTO,DTESTE,"
                                + "RCOMPLEMENTO,RCTESTE,ESPEC_MIN,ESPEC_MAX,ESPEC_UNID,ESPEC_TEXTO,REFERENCIA,"
                                + "FREQUENCIA,FREQ_UNID,PRODUTO,ORIGEM,RTIPO,ESPECIFICACAO,FREQ_TEXTO,LAB,"
                                + "ENCONTRADO,ENCONT_TEXTO,OBS,APROVADO,DATA,HORA,REGISTRO) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
//                System.out.println();
                int Ordem = Integer.parseInt(CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 1).toString());//1
                String Linha = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 2).toString());//2
                String Linha_Tipo = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 3).toString());//3
                String Setor = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 4).toString());//4
                int Perfil = Integer.parseInt(CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 5).toString());//5
                String Bpcs = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 6).toString());//6
                String Desc_Perfil = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 7).toString());//7
                String Projeto = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 8).toString());//8
                String OEM = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 9).toString());//9
                String Nº_Desenho = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 10).toString());//10
                String Nº_Plano = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 11).toString());//11
                String Operação = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 12).toString());//12
                String Equipamento = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 13).toString());//13
                String Desc_Teste = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 14).toString());//14
                String Complemento = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 15).toString());//15
                String Cod_Teste = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 16).toString());//16
                float Espec_Min = Float.parseFloat(CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 17).toString());//17
                float Espec_Max = Float.parseFloat(CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 18).toString());//18
                String Espec_Unid = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 19).toString());//19
                String Espec_Texto = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 20).toString());//20
                String Referência = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 21).toString());//21
                int Frequência = Integer.parseInt(CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 22).toString());//22
                String Freq_Unid = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 23).toString());//23
                String Produto = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 24).toString());//24
                String Origem = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 25).toString());//25
                String Tipo = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 26).toString());//26
                String Especificação = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 27).toString());//27
                String Freq_Texto = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 28).toString());//28
                String Laboratorio = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 29).toString());//29
                String Resultado_Numerico = resultado_numerico;//30
                String Resultado_Texto = resultado_texto;//31
                String Observação = observacao;//32
                String Aprovado = aprovado;//33

                pst.setInt(1, Ordem);//1
                pst.setString(2, Linha);//2
                pst.setString(3, Linha_Tipo);//3
                pst.setString(4, Setor);//4
                pst.setInt(5, Perfil);//5
                pst.setString(6, Bpcs);//6
                pst.setString(7, Desc_Perfil);//7
                pst.setString(8, Projeto);//8
                pst.setString(9, OEM);//9
                pst.setString(10, Nº_Desenho);//10
                pst.setString(11, Nº_Plano);//11
                pst.setString(12, Operação);//12
                pst.setString(13, Equipamento);//13
                pst.setString(14, Desc_Teste);//14
                pst.setString(15, Complemento);//15
                pst.setString(16, Cod_Teste);//16
                pst.setFloat(17, Espec_Min);//17
                pst.setFloat(18, Espec_Max);//18
                pst.setString(19, Espec_Unid);//19
                pst.setString(20, Espec_Texto);//20
                pst.setString(21, Referência);//21
                pst.setInt(22, Frequência);//22
                pst.setString(23, Freq_Unid);//23
                pst.setString(24, Produto);//24
                pst.setString(25, Origem);//25
                pst.setString(26, Tipo);//26
                pst.setString(27, Especificação);//27
                pst.setString(28, Freq_Texto);//28
                pst.setString(29, Laboratorio);//29
                pst.setString(30, Resultado_Numerico);//30
                pst.setString(31, Resultado_Texto);//31
                pst.setString(32, Observação);//32
                pst.setString(33, Aprovado);//33

                pst.setString(34, txt_data.getText());
                pst.setString(35, txt_hora.getText());
                pst.setString(36, txt_registro.getText());
                pst.executeUpdate();

            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

lembrando que quero entrar com a data no formato normal, mas quando for para outra tela onde é salvo, quero que venha no farmato correto.

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Está salvando data como string no banco?

Comment: Sinceramente, esse código ta bem confuso de entender.

Comment: estou salvando como datetime. qual sua duvida diego?

Comment: Mas se seu campo é datetime, porque você usa `setString` para salvar data na sua query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não consegui entender bem o seu código, mas pelo que entendi você está procurando uma forma de converter diferentes **strings** com formato de data certo?

Exemplo para converter dos dois tipos

Este código esta longe de ser o mais limpo, fiz desta forma para tentar detalhar bem o passo a passo

03-07-2017 -> 2017-07-03:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException; 

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
        //Valor inicial
        String dataFormato1 = "03-07-2017";

        //Formato do valor inicial
        SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

        //Converte para o tipo data
        Date data = formato.parse(dataFormato1);

        //Imprime o valor na nova string com o novo formato (RESULTADO: 2017-07-03)
        String dataFormato2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(data);
        System.out.println(dataFormato2);

      } catch (ParseException e) {            
        System.out.println("Falha ao converter datas");
      }
  }
}
```

2017-07-03 -> 03-07-2017:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException; 

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
        //Valor inicial
        String dataFormato1 = "2017-07-03";

        //Formato do valor inicial
        SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        //Converte para o tipo data
        Date data = formato.parse(dataFormato1);

        //Imprime o valor na nova string com o novo formato (RESULTADO: 03-07-2017)
        String dataFormato2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(data);
        System.out.println(dataFormato2);

      } catch (ParseException e) {            
        System.out.println("Falha ao converter datas");
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: obrigado por me ajudar José, mas como eu indico a data do "txt_data" que deve ser mudada?

Comment: Você pode converter este meu código para uma função, e passar o valor inicial por parâmetro e retornar a string com o valor final